# Would like to pass variable value to same jsp

Tags: javascript, jsp

Am trying to retrieve variable value which is passed from list to jsp code with in same page. Here is sample code:

```
<form>
<table>
<tr>
<td>Heading : </td>
<td>
<select id="heading" name="program" onchange="return setValue();"/>
<option value="">New</option>
<!--Database connection and retreving value and displaying in option tag -->
<option value="<%=rs.getString(1)%>"><%=rs.getString(1)%></option>
</select>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
</html>
```

and i have written script code where i can pick the value selected in list box and store it into a variable, code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function setValue(){
        alert("Inside method");
        alert(document.getElementById("heading").value);
        var heading=document.getElementById("heading").value;
        alert(heading);
        //window.location.replace("addMenuItem.jsp?menuMain="+menuMain);    
        return true;
}
</script>
```

It is displaying value. I need that value to be displayed in scriptlet as a variable.

Provide me suggestions to go ahead.

Thank you in Advance.

Comment: Scriplets are used embed java code into jsp pages javascript can access content on the page and write it on to document but cant interact with java code let me ask you what are you trying to do are trying to use it as parameter in url

Comment: I would like to grab that value and pass it to database query and check for another fields. My code am trying to is all about i have 3 fields lets say Heading, Level1 and Level2. As of now am picking value from Heading through database query and publishing it at javascript and again that value i would like to grab it into variable and would like to perform another query. If you have better idea suggest.

Comment: Did you check out my answer its just for that instead of passing it a java variable (which is not possible javascript to java value passing is not possible) then just like how you got the value of heading with request.getParameter("program") just add hidden field into your code then access hidden field's value request.getParameter("HiddenParam") then and add document.getElementById("heading").value=heading; to scripting function set heading value to hidden field if you want another two text values use 2 hidden fields and do the above things

Answer (score 0):

### There is another work  around Add hidden field

```
  <input id="HiddenParam" name="HiddenParam" type="hidden" />
```

Then

```
var heading=document.getElementById("heading").value;
    document.getElementById("heading").value=heading;
```

later like any other parameter  you can access it with
 `request.getParameter("heading");`
 In server side
  if you are trying send it as a parameter using query string

Comment: when i do with the same code which you have shared am getting null value. I require value.

Comment: Okay i will give you a sample

Answer (score 0):

```
// java script
function getPD()
{
    var data=$('#effortsInHours').val();
if(data != null)
{
    var pd = data/8;
    //alert("PD: " +pd);  
    document.getElementById("effortsInPDs").value=pd;
}

}


// form field
<S:textfield name="effortsInHours" id="effortsInHours" key="effortsInHours" size="40"> </S:textfield>

<S:textfield name="effortsInPDs" id="effortsInPDs" key="effortsInPDs" size="40"  onclick="getPD();"> </S:textfield>
```

Comment: Can you also add some explanation?